# Test Class: System.DmlException: Insert Failed: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING

Tags: apex, unit-test

Good day please kindly assist me with my test class, I have no idea what I am missing but I am constantly getting the **System.DmlException: Insert Failed: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing: [ParentId]:[ParentId]**

Find below the test class, thanks for the help:

```
   @isTest (seeAllData=true)
   public class CIFController_test 
   {
    static testMethod void CIFControllerTest()
    {
    test.startTest();
        Lead newLead= new Lead
            (
                lastname = 'TestCase',
                company = 'BrianCp',
                Business_Declaration_Date__c = date.today(),
                CEO__c = 'TestCase',
                CFO__c = 'TestCase',
                HCC__c = 'TestCase',
                CEO_Date__c = date.today(),
                CFO_Date__c = date.today(),
                HCC_Date__c = date.today(),
                Registered_Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Date_Of_Registration__c = date.today(),
                Customer_Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Business_Profile__c = 'TestCase',
                Telecommunications_Licences_if_any__c = 'TestCase',
                Surname_and_First_Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Job_Title__c = 'TestCase',
                Telephone_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Email__c = 'TestCase@mymail.com',
                Trading_As__c = 'TestCase',
                VAT_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Registration_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Registered_Address__c = 'TestCase',
                Business_Address__c = 'TestCase',
                Billing_Contact_Telephone_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Postal_Address__c = 'TestCase',
                Billing_Address_if_not_same_as_above__c = 'TestCase',
                Billing_Contact_Surname_Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Website__c = 'http://www.test.case',
                Billing_Contact_Email_Address__c = 'TestCase@mymail.com',
                Name_and_Address_of_Auditors__c = 'TestCase',
                Bank__c = 'TestCase',
                Branch_Name_and_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Account_Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Account_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Account_Type__c = 'TestCase',
                Name_of_Authorised_Bank_Signatory__c = 'TestCase',
                Street_Name_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Building_Name__c ='TestCase',
                Floor_and_Room_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Suburb__c = 'TestCase',
                City_Postal_Code__c = 'TestCase',
                Contact_Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Contact_Fixed_Telephone_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Contact_Mobile_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Contact_Email__c = 'TestCase@mymail.com',
                If_answered_Yes_for_such_payment__c = 'TestCase',
                Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Designation__c = 'TestCase',
                A_Government_Official__c = true,
                An_Official_of_an_International_Org__c = true,
                A_Member_of_Political_Party__c = true,
                A_Candidate_for_Gvt_Office__c = true,
                Representative_Employee_of_any_above__c = true,
                A_Relative_of_Any_Above__c= true,
                Improper_Payment_Within_Past_5_yrs__c = true,
                Company__c= true,
                If_answered_Yes_to_any_of_the_above__c = 'TestCase',
                Partnership__c= true,
                Trust__c= true,
                Non_Profit_Association__c= true,
                Other__c= true,
                dat__c = date.today()
            );
                insert newLead;

                Attachment attach = new Attachment();     
                attach.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
                Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
                attach.body=bodyBlob;
                attach.parentId=newLead.id;
                insert attach;

                List<Attachment> attachments=[select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:newLead.id];
                System.assertEquals(1, attachments.size());


                test.stopTest(); 

   }
 }
```

Comment: first insert lead, then only it will generate id after that insert attachment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please insert Lead before assigning to attach.

Just now i updated your code please check and let me know

Comment: thanks @ncmouli I tried that but I am now getting     System.DmlException: Insert failed.INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

Comment: Please remove see (seeAllData=true) and final attachment query in your code and try againg

Comment: Thanks  a lot @ncmouli your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome @user23

Answer (score 1):

Seems, you have missed to insert Lead record.

First, you need to insert Lead record, then you can use Lead Id to As ParentId for Attachment.

```
 @isTest (seeAllData=true)
   public class CIFController_test 
   {
    static testMethod void CIFControllerTest()
    {
    test.startTest();
        Lead newLead= new Lead
            (
                lastname = 'TestCase',
                company = 'BrianCp',
                Business_Declaration_Date__c = date.today(),
                CEO__c = 'TestCase',
                CFO__c = 'TestCase',
                HCC__c = 'TestCase',
                CEO_Date__c = date.today(),
                CFO_Date__c = date.today(),
                HCC_Date__c = date.today(),
                Registered_Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Date_Of_Registration__c = date.today(),
                Customer_Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Business_Profile__c = 'TestCase',
                Telecommunications_Licences_if_any__c = 'TestCase',
                Surname_and_First_Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Job_Title__c = 'TestCase',
                Telephone_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Email__c = 'TestCase@mymail.com',
                Trading_As__c = 'TestCase',
                VAT_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Registration_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Registered_Address__c = 'TestCase',
                Business_Address__c = 'TestCase',
                Billing_Contact_Telephone_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Postal_Address__c = 'TestCase',
                Billing_Address_if_not_same_as_above__c = 'TestCase',
                Billing_Contact_Surname_Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Website__c = 'http://www.test.case',
                Billing_Contact_Email_Address__c = 'TestCase@mymail.com',
                Name_and_Address_of_Auditors__c = 'TestCase',
                Bank__c = 'TestCase',
                Branch_Name_and_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Account_Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Account_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Account_Type__c = 'TestCase',
                Name_of_Authorised_Bank_Signatory__c = 'TestCase',
                Street_Name_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Building_Name__c ='TestCase',
                Floor_and_Room_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Suburb__c = 'TestCase',
                City_Postal_Code__c = 'TestCase',
                Contact_Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Contact_Fixed_Telephone_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Contact_Mobile_Number__c = 'TestCase',
                Contact_Email__c = 'TestCase@mymail.com',
                If_answered_Yes_for_such_payment__c = 'TestCase',
                Name__c = 'TestCase',
                Designation__c = 'TestCase',
                A_Government_Official__c = true,
                An_Official_of_an_International_Org__c = true,
                A_Member_of_Political_Party__c = true,
                A_Candidate_for_Gvt_Office__c = true,
                Representative_Employee_of_any_above__c = true,
                A_Relative_of_Any_Above__c= true,
                Improper_Payment_Within_Past_5_yrs__c = true,
                Company__c= true,
                If_answered_Yes_to_any_of_the_above__c = 'TestCase',
                Partnership__c= true,
                Trust__c= true,
                Non_Profit_Association__c= true,
                Other__c= true,
                dat__c = date.today()
            );

            insert newLead; // Insert Lead record

                Attachment attach = new Attachment();     
                attach.Name='Unit Test Attachment';
                Blob bodyBlob=Blob.valueOf('Unit Test Attachment Body');
                attach.body=bodyBlob;
                attach.parentId=newLead.id;
                insert attach;

                List<Attachment> attachments=[select id, name from Attachment where parent.id=:newLead.id];
                System.assertEquals(1, attachments.size());


                test.stopTest(); 

   }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Devendra thanks for your response, sorry I am still new to Apex/Salesforce where shopuld I insert the Lead Record???

Comment: @user23 I have just updated the code in my answer. Added the insert statement. Hope, this should work for you !

Comment: thank you very much I tried that as specified but am getting the error below:  System.DmlException: Insert failed.INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

Comment: You need to remove the last insert newLead statement. You are inserting an Lead record twice. I have updated the code again.

Comment: Thank you very much Devendra.. Your assistance is greatly appreciated

Comment: @user23 Glad, It helped you !

Answer (score 0):

Before you insert the lead it does not have an Id, therefore this line:

```
attach.parentId=newLead.id;
```

will evaluate to:

```
attach.parentId=null;
```

And this gives you the error you are facing. To fix it you should insert the lead before assigning its' Id anywhere